# Detecting File Upload and downloads activity

Tags: c#

I Would like to detect the file name which was uploaded and downloaded in system but I couldn't find any solution ,Is there any possibilities to detect those activities?

I am just looked network traffic activity, but I couldn't reach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FileSystemWatcher`  to monitor downloading and uploading.

- The Created event is triggered when a new file is uploaded.
- The Changed event is triggered when a file is downloaded or modified.
- The Deleted event is triggered when a file is deleted.
- The Renamed event is triggered when a file is renamed.

Refer the below code for reference:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Specify the directory to monitor
        string pathToMonitor = @"C:\Path\To\Your\Directory";

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(pathToMonitor);

        // Subscribe to the events you are interested in
        watcher.Created += OnFileCreated;
        watcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
        watcher.Deleted += OnFileDeleted;
        watcher.Renamed += OnFileRenamed;

        // Enable the watcher
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the application.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    private static void OnFileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File created: {e.Name}");
        // You can perform additional actions when a file is created
    }

    private static void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File changed: {e.Name}");
        // You can perform additional actions when a file is changed
    }

    private static void OnFileDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File deleted: {e.Name}");
        // You can perform additional actions when a file is deleted
    }

    private static void OnFileRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"File renamed: {e.OldName} to {e.Name}");
        // You can perform additional actions when a file is renamed
    }
}
```